# Create events with a specific Id

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, outlook-graph-api

I need to create events that are "updated" by an external application.
Every time an entity is updated on the application (e.g: the description) I have to mirror that to the corresponding event in the Outlook calendar.

The idea is to avoid storing the calendar event ids in a database.
To do that the initial solution was to give to those events the same id as the entities that are on the application.
Unfortunately this seems to be not possible on microsoft-graph-api as the Id is read-only.
The other options are:

- Open extensions

  - Seems that they are not queryable. I can't filter for a value of the extension, correct?
- Extended properties

  - Works and provides a way to filter using single value extended properties (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/singlevaluelegacyextendedproperty-post-singlevalueextendedproperties?view=graph-rest-1.0). My only concerns are that I can't understand if this is a legacy/deprecated/going to be deprecated approach or if it's valid
- Schema extensions

  - Haven't checked that option. Pros/cons?

Is there any other way to solve that requirement?
Any hint to share?

Many thanks in advance